# Can't write on HDD

Tags: 20.04

I'm new to ubuntu. I was using it alongside of windows(dual boot). Everything was fine but some days ago i noticed that all of my folders in HDD partions have a lock icon, also i can't download files(write ) on HDD partitions. The only partion that I can write/download is root. I reinstalled ubuntu but problem exists.

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Start feature.

Comment: Probably because the file system is locked to READ ONLY status... probably because of some potential disk failure. Edit your question and show me the `Disks` app **SMART Data** window for that drive. Also run `fsck` on it (let me know if you need instructions).

Comment: @Pilot6, your method solved the problem. Thanks a lot man, I appreciate it.

Comment: Is it just the Windows partition you can't write to?  Or your home directory on Ubuntu as well?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

This is a classic, (in my opinion anyway) read-only problem: I've had this issue too many times in my life;

### **Use this as a last resort.**

This always (for me) ad it fixed:

**IT GOES WITHOUT SAYING** Backup anything important before continuing!

```
ntfsfix /dev/yourdisk
```

Hope it solves your issue!

//Regards

Comment: Should "yourdisk" be replaced by disk's name?

Comment: @SudiptoBorun Like this:   /dev/sda1  (e.g if your disk is sda1)  (Find out by either:  typing in a terminal:  lsblk   Or,  df --human-readble  Or, If you prefer the gui-way:  gnome-disks -> look up the location of it :)

Comment: Same story here about ntfsfix...

Comment: @heynnema thanks, Edited my answer, improved some grammar too when I now was editing

Comment: That's fine... but who says that the OP is talking about a NTFS disk, vs their normal Ubuntu boot disk, which is ext4?

Comment: @heynnema I assumed it was ntfs;  because he was booting alongside windows? Isn't the disks he's using NTFS?  & I (2nd) assumed it was NTFS because of Pilot6's comment; (I guess?) (Or can it affect ext4 FS's too?)   Sorry Confused right now; I must be a pain.

Comment: No, Windows uses its own NTFS partition, and Ubuntu uses its own ext4 partition... and **normally** the two don't interfere with each other. Pilot6's comment is one Windows problem that can effect Ubuntu. I believe the OP is talking about problems when running Ubuntu... file system is locked.

Comment: @heynnema Yeah; I knew windows has NTFS. But I meant; can ext4 also be affected by Read only - issues from Windows?  (If that's the case; I'm shocked;I did not know that) :o

Comment: It's not read only issues from Windows... it's read only issues in Ubuntu... possibly like Pilot6's comment, or possibly because of disk-related problems. See my answer.

Comment: @heynnema I just wanted to say thank you for pointing these thing out! I've learned  pretty much just from this (quite, long - my bad) comments!  //Thanks!